# HTML/CSS Page not scrollable

Tags: html, css, scroll

On big screens, my page has this black/grey stroke I can't see on smaller screens. My page just doesn't seem to scroll down.
I used overflow-y: scroll; in body.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: #262626;
  background:url("backgroundmusic.gif") no-repeat,-webkit-linear-gradient(#404040 , #0d0d0d); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: url("backgroundmusic.gif") no-repeat,-o-linear-gradient(#404040, #0d0d0d); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: url("backgroundmusic.gif") no-repeat,-moz-linear-gradient(#404040, #0d0d0d); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: url("backgroundmusic.gif") no-repeat,linear-gradient(#404040 , #0d0d0d); /* Standard syntax */

}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #262626;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #b3b3b3;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 18px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
 color:white;
}

li img {
 padding-left: 0px;
}

h1 {
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;
 font-size: 65px;
 letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}

h3 {
 text-align: center;
 color: #f2f2f2;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 22px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 line-height: 55px;
}

.midtext {
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 margin-bottom: 0%;
 margin-top: 5%;
}

.midtext-content {
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: left;
 color: white;
 font-size: 30 px;
 letter-spacing: 0.8px;
 line-height: 35px;
 word-spacing: 0.5px;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 7px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  text-align: left;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #262626;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: #bfbfbf;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #4d4d4d;
       color: white;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>
  Hip Hop Music
 </title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300|Varela" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hiphop.css">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li><a href="hiphop.html"><img src="hiphop.png" alt="HIPHOP" style="width:120px;height:18px;"></a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">History</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="Reggae.html">Reggae</a>
      <a href="OldSchool.html">Old-School</a>
      <a href="Modern.html">Modern</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Playlists</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="PlaylistReggae.html">Reggae Playlist</a>
      <a href="PlaylistOldSchool.html">Old-School Playlist</a>
      <a href="PlaylistModern.html">Modern Playlist</a>
   <a href="* Nog in te vullen *">Your Playlist ?</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://www.google.com">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<h1>Defining Relevant Music</h1>
<h3>Welcome to the world of Hip Hop music</h3>
<h4 class="midtext">
 <div class="midtext-content">
 Altijd al meer willen weten over Hip Hop? Dan is deze site voor<br>
 jou. Alles over Hip Hop muziek. Van de geschiedenis tot verschillende<br>
 stijlen (met tracks!) om je een idee te geven wat Hip Hop muziek nou<br>
 eigenlijk inhoudt.
 </div>
<h4>

<div class="footer">©Mats László & Betien Baziany inc.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Scrolls fine for me!

Comment: Scroll is actually working fine, the thing is, it will only show up if the content will no longer fit in the viewport. please take note of that

Answer (score 0):

You need to also set the height of your html:

```
html {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: #262626;
  background: url("backgroundmusic.gif") no-repeat, -webkit-linear-gradient(#404040, #0d0d0d);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: url("backgroundmusic.gif") no-repeat, -o-linear-gradient(#404040, #0d0d0d);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: url("backgroundmusic.gif") no-repeat, -moz-linear-gradient(#404040, #0d0d0d);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: url("backgroundmusic.gif") no-repeat, linear-gradient(#404040, #0d0d0d);
  /* Standard syntax */
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #262626;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 18px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: white;
}
li img {
  padding-left: 0px;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;
  font-size: 65px;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}
h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 55px;
}
.midtext {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
  margin-top: 5%;
}
.midtext-content {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30 px;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
  line-height: 35px;
  word-spacing: 0.5px;
}
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 7px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  text-align: left;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #262626;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: #bfbfbf;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  color: white;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Hip Hop Music
  </title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300|Varela" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hiphop.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="hiphop.html">
        <img src="hiphop.png" alt="HIPHOP" style="width:120px;height:18px;">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">History</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="Reggae.html">Reggae</a>
        <a href="OldSchool.html">Old-School</a>
        <a href="Modern.html">Modern</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Playlists</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="PlaylistReggae.html">Reggae Playlist</a>
        <a href="PlaylistOldSchool.html">Old-School Playlist</a>
        <a href="PlaylistModern.html">Modern Playlist</a>
        <a href="* Nog in te vullen *">Your Playlist ?</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <h1>Defining Relevant Music</h1>
  <h3>Welcome to the world of Hip Hop music</h3>
  <h4 class="midtext">
 <div class="midtext-content">
 Altijd al meer willen weten over Hip Hop? Dan is deze site voor<br>
 jou. Alles over Hip Hop muziek. Van de geschiedenis tot verschillende<br>
 stijlen (met tracks!) om je een idee te geven wat Hip Hop muziek nou<br>
 eigenlijk inhoudt.
 </div>
<h4>

<div class="footer">©Mats László & Betien Baziany inc.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Didn't do much. Thanks for your answer anyway. ;)

Comment: Hmm? I edited the post to include your code example, which seems to work for me with the added piece of code. The background-gradient fills the whole page on big screens and scrolling works fine, too.

Comment: You can remove the `overflow-y: scroll` from the body as well to get rid of the scrollbar when it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
  overflow-y: auto
}
```

Should fix it.